# Reading large amount of data from bluetooth

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

I am looking at designing an app that would communicate with bluetooth. It will b receiving a huge amount of data. I am talking about almost 2 MB of data per second and processing it.

What would be the right way to do it (in terms of performance)?

Thanks

Comment: 2 Mega bits or 2 Mega Bytes?

Comment: Mega Byte. like what windows file size says (MB)

Comment: Bluetooth 3.0 + HS is capable of transfer that amount of data per second, Bluetooth 2.0 and previous won't be able to transfer 2 MB/s. You can't compress the file?

Comment: I am actually asking about reading the data on the Android phone. The bluetooth device is external and it is sending large amoint of data which I want to read on the phone